# Expose extended controller using swagger and Swashbuckle

Tags: c#, asp.net, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

Our team opted to start by defining a yaml file first and generating server stubs using swagger code-gen.

**Question 1**
Is this the standard way to design asp.net core 2 APIs?

**Question 2**
How can we just expose extended controller. Say we use swagger generated api controller as base class and override the existing method in a different file so that we can keep generated code untouched. When I try to host this project using swachbuckle I end up getting "System.NotSupportedExceptioL: HTTP method "POST" & path overloaded by actions".

```
public class BaseApiController : Controller
{ 
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("/api/data")]
        [SwaggerOperation("GetData")]
        [Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SwaggerResponse(200, type: typeof(List<Data>))]
        public virtual IActionResult GetData()
        { 
            string exampleJson = null;

            var example = exampleJson != null
            ? JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Data>>(exampleJson)
            : default(List<Tag>);
            return new ObjectResult(example);
        }
}

public class ChildApiController : BaseApiController 
{ 

        public override IActionResult GetData()
        { 
            return base.GetData();
        }
}
```

Comment: The error you are getting does not look related to the code you are showing... Do you have have a minimal project reproducing the issue? (if you don't just add one to GitHub)

Comment: Sorry to get that error you have to run the project and then goto swagger endpoint using browser. Swagger end point fails.

Comment: Your sample code has too many thing left out (Data, Tag) your code only has one HttpGet but the error shows POST ? That does not add up...

Comment: Yes I have cut down the example. You should get the same error for get or any other http verb

Comment: Try making the parent class: ``` abstract public class BaseApiController ```

Comment: Thanks do you have any comment on question 1.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157626/discussion-between-heldersepu-and-pats).